# AWS EKS kubernetes Deployments are not ready NodePort and LoadBalancer is not reachable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy pods on the EKS cluster. Below are some screen shots which shows that AWS EKS cluster is created and is active, group nodes are also active, now when i try to deploy any pod like nginx, wordpress or something else, these are not in the ready state. I tried deploying kubernetes dashboard and its in ready state, but why others are not in ready state do not know and that's why their URLs are not reachable.

also, while checking logs it says as below:
Error from server (NotFound): pods "deployment-2048-64549f6964-87d59" not found

[image: EKS Cluster is running fine]

[image: Nodes are also ready]

[image: Deployments are not ready]

[image: LoadBalancer is created]
[image: Command Line screenshot]
[image: kubectl get ingress]

Comment: Can you use `kubectl describe pod` on the pending Pods and look at their events ?

Comment: @matt thanks, it did help.describe pod helped in letting know the cause of the issue when i recreated the new Cluster(image was not getting pulled). I had to delete my earlier EKS cluster due to AWS cost so was not able to see what was the problem, but i assume that i downgraded the AWS instance from t3.medium to t3.small which might not be letting the apps to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pods are in pending state. If a Pod is stuck in Pending it means that it can not be scheduled onto a node. It can happen because there are insufficient resources of one type or another that prevent pods scheduling.

You can look at the output by `kubectl describe <deployment/pod_name>`. There will be messages from the scheduler about why it can not schedule your pod.

Comment: thanks @Sahadat describe pod helped in letting know the cause of the issue when i recreated the new Cluster(image was not getting pulled). I had to delete my earlier EKS cluster due to AWS cost so was not able to see what was the problem, but i assume that i downgraded the AWS instance from t3.medium to t3.small which might not be letting the pods to deploy.